# Check application version before doing binary deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple application where I serialize a profile handler with all profile objects in it to disk. It works great... but it just struck me that there will be problems in the future.

Next time I update the software the profiles might have changes, with new fields and properties, or some types might have changed. That will of course break the program when trying to deserialize from an earlier version.

What is the simplest and most straightforward way to solve this problem? I'm thinking there should be a way to add a few header bits to the binary file and just check them somehow.

Here's my serializer method:

```
private void SaveProfilesToDisk()
{
    var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

    string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"MyApp\MyApp.profiles");
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(fileStream, _profileHandler);
    }
}
```

And this is how I deserialize it:

```
 private ProfileHandler LoadProfilesFromDisk()
    {
        var serializer = new BinaryFormatter();

        string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"MyApp\MyApp.profiles");
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            return (ProfileHandler) serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

It would be perfectly fine for me to simply tell the user the save file is outdated, rename/delete it and create a new file.

Comment: Does it need to be in binary format, or could it be xml?

Comment: Actually, not really. I would love to be able to solve this with a binary save file, because it looks a bit nicer - but XML would be an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** *On re-reading the question I realized that it was worth noting that the AssemblyResolve event would receive the version of the assembly that the Deserializer was attempting to resolve. If all you want is an incompatible version message you could trap where the assembly name is your assembly name and the version is different than the current version and prompt accordingly.*

I agree with @smoore that the simplest approach would be to use XmlSerialization since it would be able to deserialize previous versions of profiles where non breaking changes occurred. The XmlSerializer will simply ignore fields that aren't present and will happily deserialize the ones that are.

If you do need binary serialization for some reason and if it is OK for the app to have an older version of the object then one way to do this would be not to care about the version on dererialization and to simply attempt to match and deserialize whatever properties were possible. For non breaking changes, like the addition of new properties you should be able to deserialize the older version without issue.

First register for the type resolve event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.TypeResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
```

Next add your type resolve method and for the assemblies you are interested in return your current version of those assemblies. Here is an example where I have done something like this:

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
            Assembly result = null;
            foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
                AssemblyName assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
                if (args.Name.StartsWith(assemblyName.Name)) {
                    this.LogInfo("Assembly \"" + args.Name + "\" resolved to \"" + assembly.Location + "\".");
                    result = assembly;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(result != null){
                return result;
            }else{
                this.LogError("Assembly resolution failure. An assembly named \"" + args.Name + "\" was not found.");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

If I am thinking correctly this should resolve the types to the new version and allow you to deserialize older versions where non-breaking changes have occurred. For breaking changes the simplest thing is to just catch the SerializationException and prompt the user accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I will dive into it. This is a bit above my level right now, but very educational. Thank you.

Comment: For the time being I just catch the SerializationException, tell the user to remove the bad file and then I return a new ProfileHandler object instead of the deserialized one. But I'll definitively look into your solution.